# Input Query Validation in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, validation

My Spring boot application takes sql queries as an Input. I want to validate if Input query starts with (select or show or Describe or insert or delete or update) else error.

I am not sure how to achieve this in Spring boot.

we can use startswith method in Java however I am not getting similar method in Spring boot.

Comment: have tried this in Java code. If(queryValidation(inputsql)) { if inputsql startswith("Show") || inputsql.startsWith(select)

Comment: Just use startsWith, Spring Boot is still Java

Comment: Its not taking startsWith

Comment: You must have the query as a `String` somewhere, so you can use `String.startsWith`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.